# NSTimer while in background mode is working -- but shouldn't it NOT be working?

Tags: ios, core-location

I've opted in to background location updates in an App I'm working on.

In my LocationManager class, I've got a method that looks like this:

```
- (void)beginUpdateTimer
{
    [self.updateTimer invalidate];
    self.updateTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:ForceUpdateDuration
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateWithLastKnownLocation)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:NO];

    NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runloop addTimer:_updateTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

The method `-updateWithLastKnownLocation` potentially calls beginUpdateTimer again.

In testing my app, I've discovered that the timer continues to fire upon the app moving in to the background, so long as I've enabled background location updates. Shouldn't this NOT be happening though? Can I rely on this?

Thanks!

Comment: means you want that timer should be stop when app goes in background?

Comment: No, I'm glad that it is executing the timer -- however -- i was under the impression that this was not supported behavior on iOS

Comment: Well it is supported.

Comment: Look over [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on it, provided the timer was running at the time you went into the background.

Comment: thats great -- do you know where this is documented by chance? I'm trying to find it now. I was under the impression that you'd be suspended until the system woke you up to handle location delegate callbacks

Comment: My memory is that they said this in a WWDC video a year or two ago (because they had changed it - before that, your timer would indeed be stopped as you went into the background), but there's no way I can dredge up anything more specific than that. There's a LOT of stuff about NSTimer in the background on Stack Overflow so do some searching...

Comment: Your app is not suspended only if you provided the `location` key in your plist background modes.

Comment: @progrmr Irrelevant (though true). The question is about timers continuing to run in the background. That the app itself is not suspended in the background is a given.

Comment: Timers run when the app is not suspended.  Timers stop when the app is suspended.

Comment: @progrmr Not so. Even the app is not suspended, you can't start a timer in the background. You can only continue running a timer that was started in the foreground. That is the point.